# How to fix the "function is not defined" in an HTML onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a source code in HTML using Visual Studio Code
The Idea is create the buttons that links with functions and the context of those button is information about me like : Name, Hobby, etc..
Here is MY FULL SOURCE CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="ja">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>INTRODUCE</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1><strong>自己紹介</strong></h1> 
  <button onclick="myname()">Name</button><br><br>
  <button onclick="age()">Age</button><br><br>　
  <button onclick="homeTown()">Hometown</button><br><br>
  <button onclick="hobby()">Hobby</button><br><br>
  <button onclick="other()">Other</button><br><br>
  <button onclick="all()">All</button><br><br>
  <b><結果はコンソールで確認></b>

<script>

  function myname()
  {
  let name = "ABFFD";
  let str = "ベトナムの首都であるハノイです";
  console.log("私は"+ name+"です.");
   }
  function age(){
  let age = 23;
  console.log(age);
   }
  function homeTown()
   {
  console.log(str);
  console.log("ハノイでは名所と有名な食べ物が多くありますので,以下のリンクをご覧くだ 
  さい！");
  <a href ="https://www.whyweseek.com/must-try-vietnamese-foods-hanoi/" 
  target="_blank">ハノイでの有名な食べ物</a>;
  <a href ="http://www.vietnam-guide.com/hanoi/top10/top10-hanoi- 
  attractions.htm" target="_blank">ハノイの名所</a>;
  }
  function hobby()
  {
console.log("私の趣味は");
<a href="../ウエブプログラミングI/html/myhobby.html">こちら</a>;
  }
function other()
{
let str1='身長', str2='体重';
let a = 180, b= 64;
console.log(str1+"は"+toString(a)+"cm");
console.log(str2+"は"+toString(b)+"kg");
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I compiled it in Web console it has the "Function is not defined" like this
[image]

The other source code I have written before has worked well but with this I have trouble. Can anyone suggest a solution for it?
Thank you

Comment: In the above code, `uni` is not defined. If you give it a value like `let uni = 'uni'`, the above code works fine for the name button. The other buttons give an error because those functions are missing

Comment: Your code works perfectly in my browser

Comment: No need it works fine check out only isse is you used `uni` check out for [demo](https://codepen.io/nithinbalasubramanian/pen/LYWEWVY)

Comment: @Mohammed Azar Really? So I don't know what's wrong with my browser. I'm using Google Chrome

Comment: All I get is `Uncaught ReferenceError: uni is not defined` as expected, using your exact code, in Google Chrome.

Comment: What's the file and line number of the `Unexpected token <` error?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Your code does not contain the functions you are using

Comment: @ChrisG It is on the line 30 <a href ="https://www.whyweseek.com/must-try-vietnamese-foods-hanoi/" 
  target="_blank">ハノイでの有名な食べ物</a>;

Comment: Yeah... well, you've put HTML inside your <script>, which completely breaks it. Why didn't you show your actual document from the start? And why were you surprised when people said they're getting a different error...? If you want to go to a different page from inside a script you need `location = "myhobby.html";`. HTML is not a programming language.

Comment: @ChrisG I'm not even surprise when people said they're getting a different error. I thought the errors were just around those button I have showed at first. Copied all my code is dompting and not necessary as I thought at first. But thanks to their comment and yours I have seen my mistakes

Comment: True, you're not supposed to be dumping lengthy blocks of code. But you should at the very least post the line surrounding those that are causing errors, this would've resolved the issue immediately :)

Answer (score 0):

This fix is probably to html encode your < and > within your `<b>` tag.

so instead of:
`<結果はコンソールで確認>`

use:
`&#x3C;結果はコンソールで確認&#x3E;`

It will properly display as <結果はコンソールで確認>.

And also your 'uni' variable is non-existent.

```
function myname() {
        let uni = "missing variable";
        let name = "ABFFD";
        let str = "ベトナムの首都であるハノイです";
        console.log("私は" + name + "です." + uni + "の学生です.");
    }
```

Comment: I will post my full code here because When I shortened it I have made some mistake about the original code

Answer (score 0):

THANK YOU FOR ALL YOUR COMMENT. I THINK I HAVE KNOWN THE ISSUE!
It is not about the onclick button but about my function defenition issues that cause my web can not load the data I think. I removed those links  **href="...."**  in the function **hometown()** and **hobby()** then they worked well. Then I guess I have to make those variable in function **other()** and **all()** become global to make it work as well!

Comment: What **exactly** did you do to resolve the problem? Which are "those variables" that you made global?

Comment: @NicoHaase Look inside the function homeTown() : I haven't initialize the variable "str" which cause that function can't work. Second look at my other() function. Do you see those variable I have called and inittialized? I made them global but it didn't work and the problem is in the toString(a) and toString(b). According to Web3School those functions only works with numbers values from 2-36.

Comment: @NicoHaase When I compiled that function it only show : 身長は[undefined object]cm ( My height is[undefined object] cm // InEnglish) and so did the 2nd Line. So I initialized that 2 variables (a,b) as strings and use " console.log" to output them

Comment: The error messages you've shared in the initial post did not indicate this